# Do I need to know correlations between dependent effect sizes for multilevel meta-analysis?

Tags: r, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I am meta-analyzing with multiple effect sizes from each study.

The studies included in my meta-analysis measured the effects of participants REPEATDLY with MULTIPLE TESTS. I am trying to deal with dependent effect sizes using three-level meta-analysis.

I see, some people use three level meta-analysis without specifying correlations of effect sizes within clusters. For example, Mike Cheung's answer here ([How to best handle subscores in a meta-analysis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64289/how-to-best-handle-subscores-in-a-meta-analysis/65790#65790)), `metafor` package's example of Konstantopoulos's (2011) analysis (http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:konstantopoulos2011), and so on.

However, Hox's (2010) explanation of "multivariate meta-analysis" states "A serious limitation for multivariate meta-analysis is that the required information on the correlations between the outcome variables is often not available in the publications (p. 223)". Also, `metafor` package's explanation of Berkey et al. (1998) (http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:berkey1998), indicates that we have to know the covariance and we have to specify the variance-covariance matrix...

My question is: 
(1) if the studies REPEATEDLY measured same participants, and/or, the same participants measured with different measurements, do I need to know correlations between dependent effect sizes for the three level meta-analysis?

(2) When Do I need to know/assume correlations between dependent effect sizes (Or, covariance structure) for three-level meta-analysis?

Thank you.

---

Hox, J. J. (2010). Multilevel analysis: techniques and applications (2. ed). New York: Routledge, Taylor & Francis.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327186/is-averaging-of-log-response-ratio-and-its-variance-allowed-when-grouping-meta-a/327240#327240

Comment: I would like to ask you a follow up question, @jskaluk. I found Wolfgang's answer on CV saying that "But this model [i.e., multilevel meta-analysis] still assumes that the sampling errors of the observed outcomes/effects within a study are independent, which is definitely not the case when those outcomes are assessed within the same individuals." (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166964/multilevel-multivariate-meta-regression).

Comment: Do you think I CANNOT use multilevel modelling to my data set, where sampling errors of the observed effect sizes are not independent because same participants took tests repeatedly and I do know now the correlations? I feel we can model specifying the participant group as another level... Do you think I can do that?

Comment: You should add random effects at the study level **and** specify the covariances among the sampling errors.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Wolfgang. I am confused with the terminologies. I read several articles applying multilevel modelling to meta-analysis, such as Cheung's (2014) `Modeling dependent effect sizes with three-level meta-analysis`, and `Multivariate Meta-analysis as Structural Equation Models`. These articles explain that we do not have to know covariances among dependent effect sizes. Is this a different MLM from your demonstration of Konstantopoulos (2011; http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:konstantopoulos2011)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I realized that Cheung's (2013) `Multivariate meta-analysis as Structural Equation Models`might not be a good example to cite for my question because he uses the example that includes covariances. Moeyaert et al. (2017): `Methods for dealing with multiple-outcomes in meta-analysis: a comparison between averaging effect sizes, robust variance estimation and multilevel meta-analysis` demonstrates that multilevel modelling (ie. three-level approach) can be applied to dependent effect sizes in case we do not know the covariances. Am I understanding it accurately? Thank you

Comment: Section 6.4 in Cheung (2015) *Meta-Analysis: A Structural Equation Modeling Approach* discusses how the multivariate and three-level meta-analyses are related. The Google books provide a preview [here](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=VHFuCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA196&dq=6.4.2+Approximating+a+multivariate+meta-analysis+with+a+three-level+meta-analysis&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJh5qj-__ZAhVqxFQKHe2ZB_oQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=6.4.2%20Approximating%20a%20multivariate%20meta-analysis%20with%20a%20three-level%20meta-analysis&f=false).

Comment: Thank you very much for letting know your book, @Mike Cheung. I finished reading it, and now I understand that three-level MA can be used for dependent effect sizes when we cannot use multivariate MA because we do not know the covariance. We can also conduct multivariate three level MA, the combination of both. And probably this is what Wolfgang is suggesting.

Comment: And to my first question, if we use three-level MA, we do not have to know the covariance between dependent effect sizes, when EITHER studies measured the same participants repeatedly at different time points OR repeatedly with different types of measurements. HOWEVER, three-level MA cannot handle studies measuring the same participnats repeatedly with multiple time points AND with mulptile measurements since the clustering is not simply nested like: studies>participants>effect sizes... Am I understanding correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the same participants contribute information to multiple estimates (whether it be multiple estimates of the measure over time, multiple effects for different measures, or both), the sampling errors of the estimates are correlated and that should be accounted for by computing the covariances. In addition, one can account for possible dependency in the underlying true effects by fitting a multilevel/multivariate model. That just means that we include random effects, such that the true effects are allowed to be correlated in some form. An example analysis of this is provided [here](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:berkey1998).

A somewhat less common case arises when we have multiple estimates that are clustered within some higher level grouping variable, but the estimates within the groups are based on different sets of participants. In that case, the sampling errors are independent, but there may still be correlation among the underlying true effects. So, we then again want to add random effects that reflect this. An example analysis of this is provided [here](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:konstantopoulos2011). As was mentioned in the comments, this type of analysis/model is only appropriate when the sampling errors are uncorrelated.

A common problem with the first case (where sampling errors are correlated) is that the information needed to compute the covariances is not available. 
Some work has been done to examine whether we can ignore the covariances (i.e., assuming that they are 0) as long as we still allow the underlying true effects to be correlated (again, by adding appropriate random effects to the model). When doing that, the correlations among the sampling errors get subsumed into the correlation among the true effects. Using the example [here](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:berkey1998), you can try this out:

```
library(metafor)
dat <- get(data(dat.berkey1998))
V <- bldiag(lapply(split(dat[,c("v1i", "v2i")], dat$trial), as.matrix))
res1 <- rma.mv(yi, V, mods = ~ outcome - 1, random = ~ outcome | trial, struct="UN", data=dat)
res1
res2 <- rma.mv(yi, diag(V), mods = ~ outcome - 1, random = ~ outcome | trial, struct="UN", data=dat)
res2
```

Model `res1` allows sampling errors to be correlated (the `V` matrix includes the covariances). In model `res2`, we use `diag(V)`, so only the diagonal of the `V` matrix is used. As you will find, the correlation among the true outcomes is `0.6088` in `res1` and `0.7752` in `res2`. Since we (incorrectly) assume that the covariances among the sampling errors are zero in `res2`, the model tries to compensate for this by increasing the correlation among the underlying true effects.

Model `res2` can work okay for making inferences about the fixed effects (i.e., for testing and constructing confidence intervals for the estimated average effects). But we know that the model is misspecified, so it isn't ideal.

A possible remedy is to use cluster-robust inference methods after having fitted a model like `res2`. For the example above, this would be:

```
robust(res2, cluster=dat$trial)
```

The cluster-robust inference approach tries to "fix up" the standard errors of the estimates of the fixed effects. You will see in the example that the SEs are quite a bit larger now. Asymptotically (i.e., when the number of clusters gets large), this approach should provide appropriate SEs (but that's unlikely to be the case in this example, since there are only 5 studies).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation, @Wolfgang. Because of being a non-native speaker of English and my limited understanding of statistics, I am having difficulty understanding your explanations. I would appreciate it if I could ask you several more follow-up questions. First, I cannot understand why each effect size (or, `trial`) has covariance value (i.e., `v2i1`) in the Berkey et al.'s example (http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses:berkey1998). Isn't there only one covariance value between PD and AL in each study?

Comment: Second, so if I am understanding correctly, Konstantopoulos's (2011) example can be fitted three-level MA without specifying covariances because effect sizes are not correlated by sampling error but by hierarchy. Is that right? If that’s the case, three-level model should not be fitted in cases where participants were repeatedly measured and/or measured with multiple measurements without specifying covariances. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Third, I am also not sure what exactly `res2` is fitting. If the `res2` is the example of the case where we fit the model without specifying the covariance but with random effects (i.e. hierarchy structure), we do not even need to put the diagonal of the V matrix, right? (Or, we cannot put diagonal since we would not know…?). What diagonal of the V matrix means here? As far as I understand, `robust()` can be used without specifying V matrix but just specifying random effect (i.e., hierarchy structure)… right? Or, am I missing something?

Comment: 1) There is one covariance per trial. So, for example `0.0030` for trial 1. 2) Correct (at least, we know that the model is misspecified then). 3) `res2` shows what happens when we ignore the covariances. Along the diagonal of `V` are the sampling variances. Those should always be specified.

Comment: >1) Oh, I see. So, the covariances are not the covariances between the PD and AL, but between two values to calculate each effect size (probably between different time points (e.g., pre-test & post-test) or different conditions (e.g., control group & treatment group).
>2) and 3) Thank you for clarifying. Now I understand that `diag(V)` represents the variances for effect sizes.

Comment: 3. I found the your answer suggesting three-level MA here (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151157/meta-analysis-is-there-a-way-of-including-dependent-effect-sizes-without-averag?rq=1). Is this example the three-level MA without specifying covariance structure, and this model is miss specified? If that’s the case, will you suggest using `robust()` to apply the cluster-robust inference method, too? If you will suggest `robust()`, what would be specified for the `cluster = ` argument? `dat$study`?, `group`?, or `obs`? (sorry for asking hypothetical questions based on my questions.)

Comment: With respect to 1: It *is* the covariance between PD and AL. With respect to your last comment: This question was about a more complex case, so discussing this just confuses things more.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my misunderstanding. So `0.0030` is the covariance for trial 1, between PD and AL, right? Then, what is `0.0077` at the next row? (as I read "The v1i and v2i values are the variances and covariances of the observed effects.", I understand as `v1i` is the variance and `v2i` is the covariance. Am I reading as it is? Or, is `v1i` and `v2i` are already a some kinds of matrix, which is the combination of variance and covariance?)

Comment: "Since each trial provides effect size estimates for both outcomes, the estimates are correlated. The `v1i` and `v2i` values are the variances and covariances of the observed effects. In particular, for each study, variables `v1i` and `v2i` form a $2×2$ variance-covariance matrix of the observed effects, with the diagonal elements corresponding to the sampling variances of the mean differences (the first for probing depth, the second for attachment level) and the off-diagonal value corresponding to the covariance of the two mean differences."

Comment: Thank you for repeating yourself, Wolfgang. I was not understanding “diagonal element” accurately. Now I understand that `v1i` (0.0075) and `v2i` (0.0030) at the first row are the variance of PD and the covariance between PD and AL, respectively. `v1i` (0.0030) and `v2i` (0.0077) at the second row are the covariance between PD and AL (i.e., the same as the `v2i` at the first row) and the variance of AL, respectively. Sorry for taking time to understand and thank you so much for being patient with me.

Comment: After learning from your answer, I took time to educate myself about cluster robust variance estimation, and figured out how to apply it to my data by controlling the random effects and the correlation of sampling errors by using 'metafor' and 'clubSandwich' packages. Thank you so much, @Wolfgang. I am wondering if you know any publications that applied cluster robust estimation while controlling the hierarchical correlation (by specifing random effects), I would really appreciate it if you could let me know. I could not find them by myself. Thank you very much.